# Plugin for Visual Studio to Mimic Eclipse's "Open Type" or "Open Resource" Keyboard Access

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

If you've ever used Eclipse, you've probably noticed the great keyboard shortcuts that let you hit a shortcut key combination, then just type the first few characters of a function, class, filename, etc. It's even smart enough to put open files first in the list.

[image]

I'm looking for a similar functionality for Visual Studio 2008. I know there's a findfiles plugin on codeproject, but that one is buggy and a little weird, and doesn't give me access to functions or classes.

Answer (score 24):

Vs11 (maybe 2010 had it too) has the Navigate To... functionality which (on my machine) has the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> shortcut.

By the way it understands capitals as camelcase-shortucts (eclipse does so too). For instance type HH to get HtmlHelper.

Comment: wow...and i thought the best they came up with was "Search Solution Explorer" (`CTRL+;`).  This is way nicer.  Between this one and `CTRL+Q` Quick Launch for menu items, you'll never need your mouse again.

Answer (score 9):

This isn't exactly the same as Eclipse from your description, but Visual Studio has some similar features out of the box (I've never used Visual Assist X, but it does sound interesting).

The Find ComboBox in the toolbar ends up being a sort of "Visual Studio command line". You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (by default) to set focus there, and Visual Studio will insert an ">" at the beginning of the text (indicating that you want to enter a command instead of search). It even auto-completes as you type, helping you to find commands.

Anyway, to open a file from there, type "open <filename>". It will display any matching files in the drop down as you type (it pulls the list of files from the currently open solution).

To quickly navigate to a function, in the code editor press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to start an incremental search. Then just start typing until you find what you are looking for. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to cancel the search, or <kbd>F3</kbd> to search again using the same query. As you are typing in the search query, the status bar in the lower left corner will contain what Visual Studio is searching for. Granted, this won't search across multiple files (I've never used Eclipse much, but that sounds like what it does from your description), but hopefully it will help you at least a little bit.

Comment: +1; just specify the VS version that has this "out of the box". Also the Incremental search is not quite as awesome as Resharper's. I forget exactly why because it's been a while, but I recall it to be the case.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone stumbles upon this thread:

There's a free plugin (created by me) for Visual Studio 2008 that mimics the Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> Open Resource dialog (note, not the Open Type dialog). It works with any language and/or project type.

You can find it at [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e4e906ee-2a2a-459b-85e8-df4b1c5666d1).

Answer (score 2):

Some of the neat features are available in Visual Assist X, though not all of them. I've asked on their forums, but they haven't appeared as yet. VAX gets updated regularly on a rough 4 week period for bug fixes and a new feature every couple of months.

Answer (score 2):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> keyword. Unfortunately it doesn't come for free.

Visual Studio doesn't have anything like this feature beyond Find.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an add-in like this to quickly navigate to source files in your project:

[image: SonicFileFinder 1.8.5]

try the Visual Studio 2005/2008 add-in [SonicFileFinder](http://jens-schaller.de/sonictools/sonicfilefinder/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread while searching for Eclipse's Ctrl+Shift+R, and after seeing the Visual Studio Gallery, found the [DPack Tools](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/Default.aspx) (they are free, and no, I'm not endorsed in any way by them).

But it's exactly what I was searching:
- Alt+U -> File Browser (a la Eclipse Ctrl+Shift+R)
- Alt+M -> Code Browser (Method list in the actual class)

It has more features, but I'm happy with these ones.

Comment: What's the difference between the "Code Browser" and the VS build in Class-View?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using biterScripting along with Visual Studio to do more flexible searching and manipulation.

1. It can search the entire workspace.
2. It can search within any project - EVEN IF THAT PROJECT IS NOT LOADED OR EVEN PART OF A WORKSPACE.
3. It can find things using regular expressions.
4. AND, ABOVE ALL, it can make bulk changes. For example, want to change the name of a class from CCustomer to CUser, I can do it in just a few command lines - Actually, I have written scripts for things like this I do often. I DON'T HAVE TO CLICK ON EACH INSTANCE AND MANUALLY DO THE CHANGE.
5. And, it is inexpensive ($0). I downloaded it from http://www.biterscripting.com .

Answer (score 0):

I'm also comming from the Java Development side and was looking for the CTRL+T feature in the Visual Studio. The other answers refer to open file, but since in C# the class name and file name can be different this is not what i was looking for.

With the **Class View** or the **Object Browser** you can search for Objects and Classes

[View]->[Class View] or [View]->[Object]